# Bash cut and grep commands through python

Tags: command-line, python, grep

I've tried to read a txt file and find the lines which contain a certain word "checkout_revision". I want to find these lines one by one in a for loop and store them in my variable, let say temp. I heard `grep` with `cut` is suitable for this. However I could not do that. Is there anyone to help me? Here is my code :

```
for line in intersect:
        cmd=""" grep "CHECKOUT_REVISION" |cut -d\'\"\' -f2"""%fst_directory
        cmd_test=os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Why do this in bash? You'd rather open the file in python (or whatever language you are using) and do this operation there.

Comment: Yea , Why I couldnt have been think that lol

Answer (score 5):

Suppose there is a file `/home/eday/test.txt` with the contents bellow:

```
this is a test


another line

CHECKOUT_REVISION this must be stored

some other things
CHECKOUT_REVISION another line to store
```

The following Python script will read the file stored in `my_file` variable looking for what is stored in `look_for` variable and if it finds a match, it will store it in `temp` variable which is a list variable.

Finally it will print to the output the contents of `temp`
You can comment out or delete the printing line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# path to the file to read from
my_file = "/home/eday/test.txt"
# what to look in each line
look_for = "CHECKOUT_REVISION"
# variable to store lines containing CHECKOUT_REVISION
temp = []

with open(my_file, "r") as file_to_read:
    for line in file_to_read:
        if look_for in line:
            temp.append(line)

# print the contents of temp variable
print (temp)
```

the above script will have the following output in terminal:

```
$ ['CHECKOUT_REVISION this must be stored', 'CHECKOUT_REVISION another line to store']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for line in open('filename'):
    if 'CHECKOUT_REVISION' in line:
        result.append(line.split('\'"\'')[1])
```

I suppose this is what you want - you get a list of strings with second field of each line which contain string `CHECKOUT_REVISION`. The question should be moved to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) though.

Comment: I want to search on a file .

Comment: @Eday well okay, if `intersect` is not a variable holding strings, then you go with `for line in open('filename'):`. It is quite simple and there's really no need for external tools, if you only check if a substring is present and then split line into records.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from above answers, here is command line version.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

pattern = sys.argv[1]
fileName = sys.argv[2]


count=0
temp = []

with open(fileName, "r") as file_to_read:
    for line in file_to_read:
        if pattern in line:
           #IN case you want to have number of hits
           count=count+1
           temp.append(line)



for i in range(count):
    print (temp[i].rstrip())
```

Run it like:

```
python "pattern" thisScript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that [Stef](https://askubuntu.com/users/12218/stef-k)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/336359/147044) is a good answer, but if you still want to use `grep` or `cut` (or others) commands from bash in python, I suggest you do not use `os.system`, but to use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. For example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

cmd = "grep CHECKOUT_REVISION /home/eday/test.txt | cut -d'\"' -f2 -s"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
temp = process.communicate()[0]

print (temp)
```

If `/home/eday/test.txt` file is something like this:

```
some lines
CHECKOUT_REVISION="revision one"
some other lines
CHECKOUT_REVISION="revision two"
other lines
```

the output of the above python script will be:

```
revision one
revision two
```

Comment: @radu-rdeanu why dont use os.system /

Comment: @Eday Using `subprocess` module you can control the stdout. `os.system` is deprecated. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5596911/2353900